# edittext still disabled after being reenabled

Tags: android

On one of the screens on my app I have a sliding bottom panel, and when it slides up I disable an EditText on the screen.
I disable it with

        `totalText.setEnabled(false);
        totalText.setClickable(false);
        totalText.setFocusable(false);`

and reenable it with 

        `totalText.setEnabled(true);
        totalText.setClickable(true);
        totalText.setFocusable(true);`

But after being reenabled the edit text still does not work. When I press it, it just blinks for a second like a keyboard is going to pop up, and nothing happens. My first thought was that maybe `totalText.setEnabled(false);` set the input type to null, but I tried replacing the setEnabled lines to setInputType and the issue remains. Anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setFocusableInTouchMode` and `setFocusable`, both of them.

Answer (score 0):

`EditText.setEnabled(!EditText.isEnabled())`   will enable and disable the `EditText`
Full cone is given below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText etInput = findViewById(R.id.et_input);
    Button btnAction = findViewById(R.id.btn_action);
    btnAction.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        etInput.setEnabled(!etInput.isEnabled());
    });
}
```

Comment: This will just cause it to toggle back and forth indiscriminate of the state I'm trying to set it to.